Create a column that counts all "Y" in all other columns for each row in Power BI
I am working in Power BI and have dataset with columns containing "Y", "N", or "NA".  There are over 100 columns so I am trying not to create an if statement for every column.  Is there any way that I can count the number of "Y" in each row for each column? With an example I could do this for the "N" as well.  Thanks in advance.  The result would be a new column that is a count of all "Y"s in the other columns.
Here is what the output is in excel (but in reality I have over 100 columns/questions):


Example data and expected output please.

Thank you for replying I put the output in the question.  Hope that helps!

I tried with this dataset:



A
B
C
D




Y
N
Y
NA


N
Y
NA
Y


NA
NA
NA
Y


Y
Y
Y
Y



I went to Transform Data -> Add Column -> Custom Column.
I used this code:
let
    columnNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Source"),
    customColumn = Table.AddColumn(#"Source", "Count of Y", each List.Sum(List.Transform(columnNames, (col) => if Record.Field(_, col) = "Y" then 1 else 0)))
in
    customColumn

Replace #"Source" with the previous step in your Power Query process. You can also change "Count of Y" to the desired new column name.
My result was:


Your output is exactly what I am looking for.  When I use the code though it is coming out as a new column that says "table" in the cells and then if I drop down from there it gives me all the columns as an option, including the new column "Count of Y".  Sorry that it won't let me include a screenshot.  The same thing is happening that happens when you use "merge queries".  I am sure I did something wrong but not sure what.

This is the modified code that I put in when I went to custom column: This is the code that I used with the source modified. let
columnNames = Table.ColumnNames(#"Replaced Value3"),
customColumn = Table.AddColumn(#"Replaced Value3", "Count of Y", each List.Sum(List.Transform(columnNames, (col) => if Record.Field(_, col) = "Y" then 1 else 0)))
in
customColumn

Very nice solution

For anyone who needs to use the code, I had to click on the cell where it said "Table" to get the results.

Yes. You have to click Table and it will automatically show up. I forgot to mention that in the comment.

Related alternative
Add column .. custom column ... with
= List.Sum(List.Transform(Record.FieldValues(_), each if _="Y" then 1 else 0))


To create all of your "results" columns, we add a "record" containing all the results columns and then expand it.
Starting with a table that contains ONLY the question columns:

you can use this code pasted into the Advanced Editor:
let

//Change Source line to reflect your actual data source
    
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WilTSAWM/RwgRqxOt5AfngyVjYwE=", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [#"Question 1" = _t, #"Question 2" = _t, #"Question 3" = _t, #"Question 4" = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source, List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),

    #"Add Results" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Results", (r)=>
        let 
            Ycount=List.Count(List.Select(Record.FieldValues(r), each _ = "Y")),
            Ncount=List.Count(List.Select(Record.FieldValues(r), each _ = "N")),
            TotalQ = Ycount+Ncount,
            Passed = Ycount/TotalQ
        in 
            [YES=Ycount, NO=Ncount, TOTAL Qs=TotalQ, #"% of audit passed="=Passed],
            type[YES=Int64.Type, NO=Int64.Type, TOTAL Qs=Int64.Type, #"% of audit passed="=Percentage.Type]
            ),
    #"Expanded Results" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Add Results", "Results", {"YES", "NO", "TOTAL Qs", "% of audit passed="}) 
            
in
    #"Expanded Results"

Results:

